# How to recursively remove first and last element with ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My array,no problem to remove first and last with slice

```
v = [ 'p','az','mo','ja','nam','o', 'da', 'rad' ]

> v.slice(1,-1)
[ 'az', 'mo', 'ja', 'nam', 'o', 'da' ]
```

How to write ES6 code that would recursively perform this operation until two elements were left?
Output

```
[ 'az', 'mo', 'ja', 'nam', 'o', 'da' ]
['mo', 'ja', 'nam', 'o']
['ja', 'nam']
```

I tried with while (i--),something was wrong with index.

Comment: What's wrong with a for loop?

Comment: @JayHales Nothug,please add your solution.

Comment: What do you mean by recursively perform this operation? What is the end result?

Comment: Please visit the [tour] _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_. You should first try it yourself and ask a specific programming question. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) _"Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer"_

Comment: Side note: "ES6" was ES2015. There have been five subsequent specification releases since then as well as several things added which will be in this upcoming annual spec snapshot. You probably don't want people to restrict themselves to just ES2015 code. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below codes shows a solution. A for loop repeats for a specified number of times performs your slice operation and saves the result back to the variable.

```js
let numberOfLoops = 3; // Change this to your correct number.
for (let i = 0; i < numberOfLoops; i++) {
   v = v.slice(1, -1);
}
```